# Port BeautifulSoup to HtmlAgility

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am trying to port this program that works from `python` to `C#` :

```
from __future__ import print_function

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('http://www.forexfactory.com/calendar.php?day=nov18.2016')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

tables = soup.findAll("table", {'class':'calendar__table'})

for table in tables:
    for row in table.findAll("tr"):
        for cell in row.findAll("td"):
            print (cell.text, end = " ")
        print()
```

This is my [code fragment] attempt in `C#` using `HtmlAgilityPack` but it doesn't work:

```
HtmlWeb browser = new HtmlWeb();
string URI = "http://www.forexfactory.com/calendar.php?day=nov18.2016";

ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

HtmlDocument document = browser.Load(URI);

foreach (HtmlNode row in document.DocumentNode.Descendants("table").FirstOrDefault(_ => _.Id.Equals("calendar__table")).Descendants("tr"))
    Console.WriteLine(row);
```

Comment: The Python code looks for `table` elements with a given *class* attribute, your C# code appears to look for a given *id* (`_.Id.Equals`). I'm not familiar with C# HTML parsing, but I'd go looking for a class equivalent instead.

Comment: And if the HTML in question assigns multiple classes to the same table, then the HTML Agility Pack won't try to untangle that. So it may need a bit of work to split the class attribute on whitespace and perform a contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query with id and for a single node using this code

```
document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@id='calendar_table']").Descendants("tr");
```

But I guess that you need to query by class, not by id, so the code will look like this

```
document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='calendar_table']").Descendants("tr");
```

Alos the class name in python code is with two `__` symbols, but in c# code with one - `_`

Comment: Thanks, you are correct on both counts - need __. This works.